# In soft-margin SVM, is it guaranteed that some points will lie on the margin?

Tags: svm, matlab

In soft-margin SVM, once we solve the dual-form optimization problem (using quadratic programming, which is guaranteed to converge on a global optimum because the problem is convex), we get a vector $\alpha$ of coefficients that we can use to recover the hyperplane parameters $\beta$ and $\beta_0$. The additional constraint in soft-margin (compared to hard-margin) is $0 \leq \alpha_i \leq C$ for some positive constant $C$. We say that:

1. If $\alpha_i = 0$, then the corresponding $x_i$ is outside the margin
2. If $\alpha_i = C$, then the corresponding $x_i$ is on the wrong side of the margin
3. If $0 \lt \alpha_i \lt C$, then the corresponding $x_i$ is on the margin

We recover $\beta$ through the KKT condition $\beta = \sum_{i}{\alpha_i y_i x_i}$, but we recover $\beta_0$ by selecting any $x_i$ whose corresponding $\alpha_i$ satisfies the third condition above and solving $y_i(\beta^T x_i + \beta_0)=1$ (we should get the same value for $\beta_0$ using any such point satisfying the third condition above).

Here's my question: given an optimal $\alpha$, is it possible for the third condition to not be satisfied for *any* $\alpha_i$? For example, I actually have a dataset that's linearly separable for which I'm trying to train a soft-margin SVM with $C=0.5$, but I'm finding that every value in $\alpha$ is either $0$ or $0.5$ and that there are no values in between, hence I cannot recover $\beta_0$. Am I doing something wrong if my $\alpha$ doesn't satisfy the third condition above for any $i$? My intuition tells me that there should always be at least two points on the margin because the primal optimization problem maximizes the size of the margin; but the $\alpha$ for my dataset is contradicting my intuition.

---

If it helps, I'm doing this in MATLAB with the following (pseudo)code:

```
X = 2 by n matrix of linearly separable data points
y = n by 1 matrix of class labels (-1 or +1)
X_hat = X with each column signed to its label
H = X_hat' * X_hat;
f = -1 * ones(n, 1);
Aeq = y';
beq = 0;
lb = zeros(n, 1);
ub = 0.5 * ones(n, 1);
alpha = quadprog(H, f, [], [], Aeq, beq, lb, ub); % alpha is always 0 or 0.5
```

Comment: Set an upper bound higher than 0.5 . If your upper bound is 0.5, you will never get an alpha higher than 0.5

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not guaranteed, but if the solution has no alpha in that open interval, then we have a "degenerate" SVM training problem, for which the optimal w=0, and we always predict the majority class.  This is shown in Rifkin et al.’s “[A Note on Support Vector Machine Degeneracy](ftp://publications.ai.mit.edu/ai-publications/pdf/AIM-1661.pdf)”, an
MIT AI Lab Technical Report.  Does your problem have these characteristics?  It seems unlikely this would happen with naturally occurring data.

Comment: Unfortunately, the link does not work for me. Do you have an updated link?

Answer (score 0):

In extremely rare case when there is no free support vectors, b would be a range of values constrained by the related KKT conditions. You can calculate that range and then pick any b in that range.

But I suggest you change the value of $C$ first and see if there is still no free SV.

Answer (score 0):

If we have a case where the solution is non-unique, then it is in fact guaranteed that there is some solution with no support vectors on the margin!

See the corollary of Theorem 2 on page 4 in this paper: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c8b8/16b48dcd4ea5b37c6bb9a238b44622eeacce.pdf